# What c++ idiom is "extern __forceinline "?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was recently reading some code and came across this idiom.

```
extern
__forceinline
int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

What is this "extern __forceinline" idiom? What does "extern" add in this case to the inline hint?

Comment: C++ does not have `__forceiline`, which means that this is unlikely to be a "C++ idiom". C language has `extern inline` contruct with a rather specific meaning (since C99). But in C++ `extern inline` has no special value.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y.aspx

Comment: The double underscore tells you that `__forceinline` is compiler specific. The effect of `extern` in that context is likely also compiler specific. It might possibly be used to suppress warnings. Anyway this is not an idiom.

Answer (score 0):

The __forceinline keyword overrides the cost/benefit analysis and relies on the judgment of the programmer instead. Exercise caution when using __forceinline. Indiscriminate use of __forceinline can result in larger code with only marginal performance gains or, in some cases, even performance losses (due to increased paging of a larger executable, for example).

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y.aspx)